# Simulating steering control using Kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I want to use Kinect to simulate a gesture which will allow the user to hold out his both hands as if holding an imaginary steering in mid air. I want to calculate the rotation angle of the vector formed between both his hands and depending upon the amount of rotation(towards his left or right) I want to fire keyboard key press. Cannot figure out how to get the rotation angle. I am using c# in wpf application. Please any help would be appreciated.

```
Vector3 hr_hl = KinectHelper.VectorBetween(skeleton, JointType.HandRight, JointType.HandLeft);
Vector3 axis_spine = new Vector3(spine.Position.Z);
float angle = (float)Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(hr_hl, axis_spine));
Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(axis_spine, hr_hl);
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);
float rot_radian = KinectHelper.QuaternionAngle(rot);
```

In short i want the amount of roll angle of the vector joining my right and left hand, my spine Z axis being the axis of rotation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was having connection problems. I have tried nothing yet. I want to implement this gesture. hold out both my hands as if i am holding the steering of a car. then as we rotate the steering i want to calculate the angle of rotation left or right and depending on the angle I want to fire windows events. can you help me get that angle??

Comment: I have drawn a vector between my right hand and left hand using the VectorBetween method given in XNA sample. I am treating the Z axis of my spine as the axis of rotation. My hand vector will be rotating around the spine Z vector. but I cannot get the angle of rotation of hand vector.

Comment: If you haven't tried anything yet, then done post a question and expect we will simply tell you how. You have to do you own research, we don't have to. But, if you already have been coding with/for the Kinect and you run into problems with that code, you can post a question here about it and also remember to include the code. Also before you post another question, you should read the [help/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page.

Comment: Vector3 hr_hl = KinectHelper.VectorBetween(skeleton, JointType.HandRight, JointType.HandLeft);
                       Vector3 axis_spine = new Vector3(spine.Position.Z);
                       
                       float angle = (float)Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(hr_hl, axis_spine));
                       Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(axis_spine, hr_hl);
                       Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);
                       float rot_radian = KinectHelper.QuaternionAngle(rot);

Comment: This is what i tried. sorry for not posting my code here. Wont happen again.

Comment: Edit your question, instead of posting it in the comment section, because it's very un-readable.